# global.json missing in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, visual-studio-2017, project.json

I just noticed that whenever we create a new project with ASP.NET core application, global.json file is not added to the project anymore.

Also, I do not see web.config file where I can keep configuration settings.

Can somebody tell me how to add these files and where should I keep my configuration settings ?

Comment: @mjwills -it helped. Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in my VS

Comment: @Umashankar Did you read the link I provided?